# Sentence Structure

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verb, tense, preterite

1. What is the name of the structure in the sentence below?

   > Alle von der Bewerberin oder vom Bewerber verfassten Dokumente müssen zudem klar **strukturiert sein.**
2. What does the structure used in the sentence imply?
3. What does the structure "perfect infinitive" imply? When do we use it? What are the similar structures to "perfect infinitive"?

Comment: I have no idea, what this question is about, nor where the example sentence exhibits a *infinitive perfect*; that seems a quite ordinary modal verb usage.

Comment: Perfect participle and infinitive are used in exactly the same way as in the corresponding English sentence (shortened for the sake of clarity) *The documents must **be structured**.*

Comment: @RHa: The question is difficult to answer because grammar terminology can vary. But I think Grammis would call the example the [Sein-Passiv](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/1108). In this case it happens to be used in the infinitive. Grammis also defines an [Infinitiv Perfekt](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/267); the explanation is over my head but I'm sure it has nothing to do with the example. I did try to answer this myself but gave up on it, but I do think it could be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I begin with #3:

*Perfect infinitive* is a construction from English grammar, not from German grammar. You use it in sentences like *»I'm happy **to have seen** this movie«* or *»You **should have called** the police«.* When you translate such an English sentence into German you get something like this: *»Ich bin froh, diesen Film **gesehen zu haben**«* or *»Du **hättest** die Polizei **rufen sollen**.«* As you see, these are two different constructions in German. So, it makes no sense to use names of English grammatical features when you talk about German grammar.

---

Now for #1:

The short version of the sentence is this:

> Die Dokumente müssen strukturiert sein.

The part *»Alle von der Bewerberin oder vom Bewerber verfassten«* is an attribute of *»Dokumente«* and *»zudem«* just means *»additionally«* and *»klar«* is *»clearly«.* All these parts are not necessary to analyze the part marked bold by you.

The whole sentence is in English:

> All documents written by the applicant must also be clearly structured.

And this is the short version:

> The documents must be structured.

The word *»strukturiert«* is an participle (Partizip II) of the verb *»strukturieren«:*

> *Infinitiv (as part of Futur I):* Wir werden unser Unternehmen **strukturieren.**
> *Partizip II (as part of Perfekt):* Wir haben unser Unternehmen **strukturiert.**

Here the word *»strukturiert«* describes an action that happened in the past. It does not describe a property of something. (**What did** we **do** with our company? - We **structured** it.)

---

But in you sentence this word is not used as a participle. It is used adjectivally (like an adjective) in your sentence:

> *"normal" adjective:* Die Dokumente müssen **schön** sein.
> *adjectivally used participle:* Die Dokumente müssen **strukturiert** sein.

Here the word *»strukturiert«* describes a property of the documents. (**How** must the documents be? - They must be **pretty**; They must be **structured**.)

So, we have a very simple construction in *Präsens* with a modal verb. The main verb is *sein.* This is a copula, and it links the adjective to the subject:

- without modal verb:

> Die Dokumenten sind strukturiert.
> <sup>*The documents are structured.*</sup>

- with a modal verb:

> Die Dokumenten müssen strukturiert sein.
> <sup>*The documents must be structured.*</sup>

In German only one verb is allowed to stand at position 2, all other verbs must move to the end of the clause. If there is a modal verb, it must stand at position 2. If there is an auxiliary verb, the auxiliary verb must be there:

- Only full verb

  > Ich **gehe** mit meinem Hund die Straße entlang.
  > <sup>*I **walk** down the street with my dog.*</sup>
- With modal verb

  > Ich **will** mit meinem Hund die Straße entlang **gehen.**
  > <sup>*I **want to walk** down the street with my dog.*</sup>
- With auxiliary verb

  > Ich **werde** mit meinem Hund die Straße entlang **gehen.**
  > <sup>*I **will walk** down the street with my dog.*</sup>
- With auxiliary and modal verb

  > Ich **werde** mit meinem Hund die Straße entlang **gehen wollen.**
  > <sup>*I **will want to walk** down the street with my dog.*</sup>